# What is the output of this c++ program?

Tags: c++, reference

i came across a c++ program to print the values of px and py. It would be nice if someone explains me, how one will get the output values as 20 and 8. Also, when one comments the line of code `location(px,py)`,the output of the code is 10 and 8. When one comments the line of code `location(py)`, the output of the code is 14 and 2. I know that as &x = px i.e, x is referenced to px when x is changed, px is also changed. But i don't understand the output values being printed. It would be grateful if someone explains me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void location(int &x, int y=4)
{
    y+=2;
    x+=y;
}
int main() {
    int px=10,py=2;
    location(py);
    location(px,py);
    cout << px << py;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could step through the code  in a debugger and watch the values of variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void location(int &x, int y=4)
{
    y+=2;
    x+=y;
}

int main() 
{
    int px=10,py=2;
    location(py);
    location(px,py);
    cout << px<<" "<< py;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20 8
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.312 s
Press any key to continue.
```

> 1) how one will get the output values as 20 and 8.

```
    location(py); //y+=2; is 6                ------  1
                  //py+=y; is 8
```

after this line py contains 8.

```
    location(px,py);  //y+=2; is 10           ------- 2
                      //px+=y; is 20
```

after this line px contains 20;

so, output is `20 8`

> 2) when one comments the line of code location(px,py)

When you comment `location(px,py);` this. The (1) only executes, so py value changes to 8 and px unchanged

so, output is `10 8`

> 3) When one comments the line of code location(py)

when you comment `location(py)` this. The (1) did not execute so py value is unchanged.The value passed to this is `location(px,py)` is 10 and 2

here

```
     y+=2;  //y=4
     px+=y; //px is 14
```

so, output is `14 2`

Note: The void `location(int &x, int y=4)`, the x is not local variable it is reference to value passed, so the change of x in the function also reflects in the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the function definition, the first argument is pass-by-reference while the second argument is pass-by-value.

When `location(py)` is called, `py` changes since it's passed by reference.

```
y += 2 // y = 6
py += y // py += 6 => py = 8
```

When `location(px, py)` is called, only `px` will change since `py` is pass-by-value.

```
y += 2 // y = 10, since py = 8
px += y // px += 10 => px = 20
```

Now, if you comment `location(px, py)` `px = 10` is unchanged while `py` has been changed to 8, hence the output.

If you comment `location(py)`, note that `py` is still (and will remain to be) equal to 2. Thus:

```
y += 2 // y = 4, since py = 4
px += y // px += 4 => px = 14
```